# SILEX Clear cache

Tags: php, caching, silex

I have the problem of the blank page with Silex on my project in production.
How do I empty the cache? I tried with `php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup -e prod`but I have this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  


There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.
```

I think that it must be different with Silex.

PS: error.log

> [Tue Aug 08 06:25:03.193526 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7269] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>   [Tue Aug 08 06:50:29.552438 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.159:46142] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/class-loader/Tests/ApcClassLoaderTest.php on line 17
>   [Tue Aug 08 06:58:03.547668 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.128:55893] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\RuntimeException' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/property-access/Exception/UnexpectedTypeException.php on line 21
>   [Tue Aug 08 07:05:37.542474 2017] [:error] [pid 16306] [client 66.249.64.159:35769] PHP Warning:  require_once(PHP/CodeCoverage/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/scripts/auto_prepend.php on line 2
>   [Tue Aug 08 07:05:37.542512 2017] [:error] [pid 16306] [client 66.249.64.159:35769] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/scripts/auto_prepend.php on line 2
>   [Tue Aug 08 07:24:32.536351 2017] [:error] [pid 16309] [client 66.249.64.157:50264] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\FileLoader' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/PhpFileLoader.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 07:28:19.541841 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.128:58273] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\MetadataInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/validator/Mapping/GenericMetadata.php on line 26
>   [Tue Aug 08 07:35:53.543901 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.157:51598] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/Helper.php on line 21
>   [Tue Aug 08 07:47:14.913694 2017] [:error] [pid 16309] [client 66.249.64.157:34110] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Twig\NodeVisitor\AbstractNodeVisitor' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/NodeVisitor/TranslationNodeVisitor.php on line 26
>   [Tue Aug 08 07:51:01.535512 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.159:56025] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/sebastian/comparator/tests/ScalarComparatorTest.php on line 17
>   [Tue Aug 08 07:58:38.766965 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.157:56495] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/routing/Tests/RequestContextTest.php on line 18
>   [Tue Aug 08 08:13:58.350715 2017] [:error] [pid 16309] [client 66.249.64.128:46170] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Fragment\AbstractSurrogateFragmentRenderer' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Fragment/EsiFragmentRenderer.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 08:21:17.664056 2017] [:error] [pid 16306] [client 66.249.64.159:56076] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\AbstractCloner' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/VarCloner.php on line 17
>   [Tue Aug 08 08:51:33.539655 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.157:52678] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/console/Style/OutputStyle.php on line 23
>   [Tue Aug 08 08:55:20.534679 2017] [:error] [pid 16308] [client 66.249.64.157:55368] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/sebastian/comparator/tests/MockObjectComparatorTest.php on line 17
>   [Tue Aug 08 09:10:28.543803 2017] [:error] [pid 16308] [client 66.249.64.157:51059] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/validator/Context/ExecutionContext.php on line 36
>   [Tue Aug 08 09:14:15.535219 2017] [:error] [pid 16310] [client 66.249.64.159:41984] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SebastianBergmann\Comparator\ObjectComparator' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/sebastian/comparator/src/DOMNodeComparator.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 09:18:08.520908 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.157:56474] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\FatalErrorHandlerInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/debug/FatalErrorHandler/UndefinedMethodFatalErrorHandler.php on line 22
>   [Tue Aug 08 09:21:49.905656 2017] [:error] [pid 16306] [client 66.249.64.157:35574] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Intl\Exception\NotImplementedException' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/intl/Exception/MethodNotImplementedException.php on line 17
>   [Tue Aug 08 09:25:36.545062 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.157:51332] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\StoreInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/Store.php on line 25
>   [Tue Aug 08 09:29:23.534251 2017] [:error] [pid 16308] [client 66.249.64.159:39327] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Extension/HttpKernelExtension.php on line 23
>   [Tue Aug 08 09:33:10.537784 2017] [:error] [pid 16500] [client 66.249.64.128:50289] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Session.php on line 27
>   [Tue Aug 08 10:07:13.911245 2017] [:error] [pid 16310] [client 66.249.64.128:53268] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\KernelEvent' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Event/FinishRequestEvent.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 10:11:00.532041 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.128:38555] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\ExceptionInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/options-resolver/Exception/AccessException.php on line 20
>   [Tue Aug 08 10:22:21.534734 2017] [:error] [pid 16310] [client 66.249.64.159:59860] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Tests/ServerBagTest.php on line 22
>   [Tue Aug 08 10:29:55.536874 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.128:53229] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\PipesInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/process/Pipes/AbstractPipes.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 10:33:42.533170 2017] [:error] [pid 16306] [client 66.249.64.159:34131] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/class-loader/Tests/ClassLoaderTest.php on line 16
>   [Tue Aug 08 10:37:29.543640 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.157:42740] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Twig\Extension\ProfilerExtension' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/web-profiler-bundle/Twig/WebProfilerExtension.php on line 27
>   [Tue Aug 08 10:41:16.547291 2017] [:error] [pid 16308] [client 66.249.64.128:57670] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/validator/Tests/ConstraintViolationListTest.php on line 18
>   [Tue Aug 08 10:45:03.646654 2017] [:error] [pid 16500] [client 66.249.64.128:48709] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Extension/WebLinkExtension.php on line 25
>   [Tue Aug 08 10:48:50.539184 2017] [:error] [pid 16310] [client 66.249.64.128:45715] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Tests/EventTest.php on line 20
>   [Tue Aug 08 10:52:37.541883 2017] [:error] [pid 16309] [client 66.249.64.157:52334] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Node\AbstractNode' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/css-selector/Node/SelectorNode.php on line 24
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:00:11.534753 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.128:49147] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ExceptionInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/routing/Exception/InvalidParameterException.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:07:45.544828 2017] [:error] [pid 16500] [client 66.249.64.157:34818] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Translation\Extractor\AbstractFileExtractor' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Translation/TwigExtractor.php on line 29
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:11:32.535271 2017] [:error] [pid 16310] [client 66.249.64.128:38970] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/options-resolver/Exception/MissingOptionsException.php on line 21
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:15:19.533083 2017] [:error] [pid 16309] [client 66.249.64.128:58115] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\AbstractTestSessionListener' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/TestSessionListener.php on line 23
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:19:06.549634 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.159:53550] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\IcuResFileLoader' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/IcuDatFileLoader.php on line 24
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:26:40.904976 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.157:44976] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Extension/WorkflowExtension.php on line 24
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:34:14.545947 2017] [:error] [pid 16310] [client 66.249.64.157:56525] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Twig\Extension\ProfilerExtension' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Extension/ProfilerExtension.php on line 21
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:39:00.892433 2017] [:error] [pid 16309] [client 66.249.64.128:59967] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/sebastian/comparator/tests/SplObjectStorageComparatorTest.php on line 20
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:41:48.905969 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.157:36836] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Asset\Exception\ExceptionInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/asset/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:49:22.545516 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.128:47457] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Node\AbstractNode' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/css-selector/Node/NegationNode.php on line 24
>   [Tue Aug 08 11:56:56.908219 2017] [:error] [pid 16500] [client 66.249.64.159:38868] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\RuntimeException' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/yaml/Exception/DumpException.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 12:08:33.812291 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.128:61181] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/console/Formatter/OutputFormatter.php on line 21
>   [Tue Aug 08 12:15:51.535456 2017] [:error] [pid 16500] [client 66.249.64.159:44380] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcherInterface.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 12:19:38.544873 2017] [:error] [pid 16310] [client 66.249.64.128:55930] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Exception/LengthRequiredHttpException.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 12:24:04.840727 2017] [:error] [pid 16309] [client 66.249.64.159:56684] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SebastianBergmann\Comparator\ObjectComparator' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/sebastian/comparator/src/DateTimeComparator.php on line 16
>   [Tue Aug 08 12:33:16.600389 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.159:42633] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/DependencyInjection/Extension.php on line 21
>   [Tue Aug 08 12:34:47.645922 2017] [:error] [pid 16308] [client 66.249.64.157:43164] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Node\AbstractNode' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/css-selector/Node/PseudoNode.php on line 24
>   [Tue Aug 08 12:38:34.540874 2017] [:error] [pid 16310] [client 66.249.64.159:33974] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArrayInput.php on line 26
>   [Tue Aug 08 12:49:55.543914 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.159:42057] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/sebastian/diff/tests/ChunkTest.php on line 18
>   [Tue Aug 08 12:53:42.532052 2017] [:error] [pid 16308] [client 66.249.64.159:36947] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Exception/NotFoundHttpException.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 13:01:16.542447 2017] [:error] [pid 16500] [client 66.249.64.159:46543] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Event/FilterControllerArgumentsEvent.php on line 29
>   [Tue Aug 08 13:16:24.538787 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.157:64124] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Field\FormField' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Field/FileFormField.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 13:20:11.536864 2017] [:error] [pid 16308] [client 66.249.64.159:60501] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Field\FormField' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Field/ChoiceFormField.php on line 21
>   [Tue Aug 08 13:27:45.545493 2017] [:error] [pid 16500] [client 66.249.64.128:55358] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\Handler\ChromePHPHandler' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/monolog-bridge/Handler/ChromePhpHandler.php on line 23
>   [Tue Aug 08 13:35:19.544757 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.128:52892] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/debug/Tests/ErrorHandlerTest.php on line 25
>   [Tue Aug 08 13:43:55.122787 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.128:35642] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\RuntimeException' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/property-access/Exception/AccessException.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 13:46:41.077227 2017] [:error] [pid 16308] [client 66.249.64.128:43032] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\MetadataInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/validator/Mapping/PropertyMetadataInterface.php on line 30
>   [Tue Aug 08 14:01:48.905705 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.157:48676] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\ExceptionInterface' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/validator/Exception/RuntimeException.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 14:05:35.541078 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.159:43117] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pcntl_signal() in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/process/Tests/NonStopableProcess.php:36\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/process/Tests/NonStopableProcess.php on line 36
>   [Tue Aug 08 14:13:50.721233 2017] [:error] [pid 16500] [client 66.249.64.157:33402] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Twig\TokenParser\AbstractTokenParser' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/TokenParser/FormThemeTokenParser.php on line 25
>   [Tue Aug 08 14:28:17.543789 2017] [:error] [pid 16307] [client 66.249.64.157:40734] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Tests/StreamedResponseTest.php on line 18
>   [Tue Aug 08 14:58:33.542618 2017] [:error] [pid 16308] [client 66.249.64.157:36831] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/UploadedFile.php on line 25
>   [Tue Aug 08 15:02:20.543169 2017] [:error] [pid 16500] [client 66.249.64.159:57796] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/console/Question/ConfirmationQuestion.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 15:06:07.549581 2017] [:error] [pid 16309] [client 66.249.64.128:33812] PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/tests/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/tests/bootstrap.php on line 3
>   [Tue Aug 08 15:06:07.549645 2017] [:error] [pid 16309] [client 66.249.64.128:33812] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/tests/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/tests/bootstrap.php on line 3
>   [Tue Aug 08 15:09:54.535547 2017] [:error] [pid 16369] [client 66.249.64.157:63682] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/routing/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 26
>   [Tue Aug 08 15:13:41.545768 2017] [:error] [pid 16306] [client 66.249.64.128:60150] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/inflector/Tests/InflectorTest.php on line 17
>   [Tue Aug 08 15:25:02.540619 2017] [:error] [pid 16500] [client 66.249.64.159:34361] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/yaml/Tests/DumperTest.php on line 19
>   [Tue Aug 08 15:36:23.538582 2017] [:error] [pid 16308] [client 66.249.64.128:53735] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\AccessException' not found in /var/www/html/roadsofearth/vendor/symfony/property-access/Exception/NoSuchIndexException.php on line 19

Comment: Did you check your error log? Silex has no cache, unless you explicitly configure it.

Comment: Seems more likely that you have a fatal error stopping php script execution. Like @Maerlyn suggested, check  your error logs.

Comment: Thanks, I have many many errors in error.log.. :/